# Generating a key from ancestor path in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a model called Request. A request is created with a parent User like so:

```
request = Request(parentUserKey)
```

Now, the key_name for a User is that user's email, so when I create a new user, I do:

```
user = User(key_name = 'abc@gmail.com')
```

So what I want to do now is to create a key using Key.from_path for a Request, so I try:

```
requestKey = Key.from_path('User', 'abc@gmail.com', 'Request', 1)
```

I put 1 because I will use this key to fetch all Requests with ID higher than 1 (or any other arbitrary int) via the following:

`requestQuery.filter("__key__ >", requestKey)`

Then for testing purposes, I try to convert the key to a string via `keyString = str(requestKey)`, but I get the following error:

`Cannot string encode an incomplete key`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on what Guido wrote, doing all of this work to manually create a key probably isn't the best approach to solve your problem. Rather, if you store all of User's Request entities in User's entity group, you can simply and straight-forwardly retrieve them with an ancestor query.

First, to make all of the Request entities children of User, we're going to slightly change the way that you instantiate a Request object:

```
request = Request(parent=parentUser) # Where parentuser is a User already in the datastore
# Do whatever else you need to do to initialize this entity
request.put()
```

Now, to get all of the Request objects that belong to User, you just:

```
requests = Request.all().ancestor(parentUser).fetch(1000)
# Obviously, you want to intelligently manage the condition of having
# more that 1000 Requests using cursors if need be.
```

Having the ability to manually create Keys using all of the path info is great, but it is also often more work than is necessary.

Does this solve your use-case?

Answer (score 1):

A key with a 0 id is not valid. Instead of that filter, use an ancestor query.

Comment: 0 is arbitrary. I just put that there for the sake of the question. I'll change it to 1

Comment: There is a big difference between 0 and 1 though. With 0, str(key) will raise an exception with the message you quote. With 1, it will return a valid encode key.